# What is inverse number in permutation?

Tags: permutations

I came across inverse number defined as - the number of transpositions of pairs of elements that must be composed to place the elements in canonical order $012\ldots(n-1)$.

Please clarify it with an example. In general is there any way to calculate it?

Comment: If you have the permutation $(0,1,2)$ the *inversion number* is $0$. For the permutation $(0,2,1)$ the inversion number is $1$ since it is enough to switch $1$ and $2$ to get it in order. For the permutation $(2,0,1)$ we switch first $2$ and $0$ to get $(0,2,1)$ and then we switch $2$ and $1$ to get $(0,1,2)$. So, inversion number is $2$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod do we have a generalized method to find the number given any random permutation of length n?

Comment: Whenever, you see a pair of entries that are not in order swap them and add $1$ to the count. Do that until the permutation is in order. In other words, you run [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) counting how many steps it took to get the permutation sorted.